# If/Switch statements evaluating the first condition only

Tags: c#, maui

Major noob question(s) here.
Depending on the button clicked by the user, I am receiving the arguments which reference a letter. That letter is what I want to evaluate and check what letter it is so that I do something. However, the following code always evaluates the first condition only so even when "C" is received in the `stem` variable, first condition gets evaluated.

**AnswerControl.xaml.cs**

```
private async void AddToNotes(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        //Create the new card to save to flashcards table
        Flashcard card = new Flashcard();
        string stem = ((Button)sender).CommandParameter.ToString();

        switch (stem)
        {
            case "A":
                card.Question = string.Join(", ", question.QuestionMain, question.ChildA);
                card.Answer = string.Join(" - ", question.AnswerA, question.ExplanationA);
                break;
            case "B":
                card.Question = string.Join(", ", question.QuestionMain, question.ChildB);
                card.Answer = string.Join(" - ", question.AnswerB, question.ExplanationB);
                break;
            case "C":
                card.Question = string.Join(", ", question.QuestionMain, question.ChildC);
                card.Answer = string.Join(" - ", question.AnswerC, question.ExplanationC);
                break;
            case "D":
                card.Question = string.Join(", ", question.QuestionMain, question.ChildD);
                card.Answer = string.Join(" - ", question.AnswerD, question.ExplanationD);
                break;
            case "E":
                card.Question = string.Join(", ", question.QuestionMain, question.ChildE);
                card.Answer = string.Join(" - ", question.AnswerE, question.ExplanationE);
                break;
        }

        //Retrieve flashpacks then send a list object to the popup
        await using var context = new DataContext();
        List<FlashcardPack> flashpacks = context.FlashcardPacks.ToList();
        var response = await Shell.Current.ShowPopupAsync(new FlashpackControl(flashpacks));

        //Convert returned object to flashcard pack object
        FlashcardPack selectedPack = (FlashcardPack)response;

        card.Question = string.Join(", ", question.QuestionMain, question.ChildA);
        card.Answer = string.Join(" - ", question.AnswerA, question.ExplanationA);
        card.FlashcardPackId = selectedPack.Id;
        card.NextDate = DateTime.Now.AddDays(4);
        
        context.Flashcards.Add(card);
        await context.SaveChangesAsync();

        Toast.Make($"5 cards added to {card.FlashcardPack}", CommunityToolkit.Maui.Core.ToastDuration.Long, 14);
    }
```

And while I am on the same topic, I am attempting to do the same below. I am receiving a `bool` and trying to evaluate what it is so that I do something with it. I have tried to now convert the bools to strings and evaluate like that but no luck.

```
        [RelayCommand]
        void AnswerResponse(string answer)
        {
            if (answer.Equals(Question.Answer.Value.ToString()))
            {
                try
                {
                    AnswerResult = "Correct";
                    AnswerVisibility = true;
                }
                catch (Exception)
                {
                    throw;
                }
                finally
                {
                    Count++;
                    GetQuizQuestion();
                }
            }
            else 
            {
                try
                {
                    AnswerResult = "Wrong";
                    AnswerVisibility = true;
                }
                catch (Exception)
                {
                    throw;
                }
                finally
                {
                    Count++;
                    GetQuizQuestion();
                }
            }
        }
```

I am sure the answer lies in my very cheap understanding of value and reference types but since strings are supposed to check equality between values, I don't know where to go.

Comment: did you set a break point on the switch and look at the contents of stem?

Comment: If you are new to step-by-step debugging, here's how to do it in [Visual Studio](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/get-started/csharp/tutorial-debugger), or in [VSCode](https://code.visualstudio.com/Docs/editor/debugging).

Comment: Yes I did. I was doing step by step debugging. Stem contains the requested letter. @NPras

Comment: Please avoid asking multiple questions in a single post

Comment: @TanakaMawere It kind of sounds like you are debugging an older version of the code. Make sure to stop the debugger, clean the solution and rebuild the projects, then try debugging again. Also, make sure you are not debugging more than one thread at the same time. You may be seeing concurrent threads with different values in a single debugging session.

Comment: *"the following code always evaluates the first condition only"*. The only way that can happen, is if `stem` always equals `A`. What is the value of `stem`, when you click a different button? Also, **add to question** the XAML of the buttons, in case the problem is there. Also, this code (near the end, just before `FlashcardPackId`) seems **suspicious:** `card.Answer = ... question.AnswerA`. Isn't that forcing the answer to always be "A"?

Comment: @ToolmakerSteve You might actually be right. Hadn't seen that at all. Let me test it out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As was suggested by @ToolmakerSteve in the comments, I had left the following bit that was making the if statement useless. It was running but the values were being changed to ChildA values.

```
card.Question = string.Join(", ", question.QuestionMain, question.ChildA);
card.Answer = string. Join(" - ", question.AnswerA, question.ExplanationA);
```

For the Boolean check, since I was comparing Booleans and receiving the answer as a string, first thing to was convert the `string answer` to  a Boolean using `bool.Parse(answer)`. The if statement is supposed to be structured as below for it to work.

```
      if (bool.Parse(answer).CompareTo(QuestionSelected.Answer) == 0)
            {
                Shell.Current.DisplayAlert("Correct", "Hooray", "Ok");
            }
            else
            {
                Shell.Current.DisplayAlert("Wrong", "Nah uh", "Ok");
            }
```

Answer (score 2):

You can check the problem by following the steps below:

1.debug step by step to check if the value of `stem` is valid.

```
 string stem = ((Button)sender).CommandParameter.ToString().Trim();
```

2.try to check the value of `stem` you received, whether it is `capitalized`, whether it contains `spaces` or other characters.

And here you are using capital letters(`A`,`B`,`C`) for comparison, so the value of `stem` should also be `capital` letters.

If the value is `lowercase`, you can convert to `uppercase` letter. If it contains spaces, you can remove them by function `Trim()`.

Please refer to the following code:

```
private  void AddToNotes(object sender, EventArgs e) 
    {
        //Create the new card to save to flashcards table
        string stem = ((Button)sender).CommandParameter.ToString().Trim();
 
        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(stem))
        {
            return;
        }

        stem =  stem.ToUpper();

        switch (stem)
        {
            case "A":
                card.Question = string.Join(", ", question.QuestionMain, question.ChildA);
                card.Answer = string.Join(" - ", question.AnswerA, question.ExplanationA);

                System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("----------------> A");
                break;
            case "B":
                card.Question = string.Join(", ", question.QuestionMain, question.ChildB);
                card.Answer = string.Join(" - ", question.AnswerB, question.ExplanationB);
                System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("----------------> B");
                break;
            case "C":
                card.Question = string.Join(", ", question.QuestionMain, question.ChildC);
                card.Answer = string.Join(" - ", question.AnswerC, question.ExplanationC);

                System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("----------------> C");
                break;
            case "D":
                card.Question = string.Join(", ", question.QuestionMain, question.ChildD);
                card.Answer = string.Join(" - ", question.AnswerD, question.ExplanationD);

                System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("----------------> D");
                break;
            case "E":
                card.Question = string.Join(", ", question.QuestionMain, question.ChildE);
                card.Answer = string.Join(" - ", question.AnswerE, question.ExplanationE);
                break;
        }

    }
```